# Node Sass version 7.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0

Tags: node-sass

I am running a react app using node (version 16.13.1). Apparantly I am supposed to use node sass version 7.0.0.

So I install version 7.0.0, but when I run my application I get this error :

```
./src/misc/loading.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/misc/loading.scss)
Error: Node Sass version 7.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
```

Why am I getting this error?

And "incompatible with 4.0.0" means what? 4.0.0 of which module? node? sass? react? npm?

Comment: What is the full path to `./src/misc/loading.scss` ? I don't see it under `node-sass/src`

Comment: loading.scss is just one of my own src files

Comment: Minimal reproducible test case is needed in order to proceed